# Customizing the views in authy-devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twilio, two-factor-authentication, authy

I am trying to implement two factor authentication via [`authy 2FA` of `twilio`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy) using `devise-authy` gem.

I want to customize the views with three pages for 2FA.

1. first page - My login page where user enters `username` and `password`, `on submit` it will be redirected to a page
2. Second page - In this page he can select the *2FA method* to receive the *code* via phone or sms after which he is redirected
3. Third page - Here he finally enters the code.

I am able to configure the first two pages.

My **PROBLEM** is that in the third page, where i am setting up the `authy form` for code verification, I am getting **error** `undefined method id for nil class`

```
<%= verify_authy_form do %>
  <legend><%= I18n.t('submit_token_title', {:scope => 'devise'}) %></legend>
  <%= label_tag :token %>
      <%= text_field_tag :token, "", :autocomplete => :off, :id => 'authy-token' %>
  <label>
  <%= check_box_tag :remember_device %>
      <span><%= I18n.t('remember_device', {:scope => 'devise'}) %></span>
  </label>

  <!-- Help tooltip -->
  <!-- You need to configure a help message. -->
  <!-- See documentation: https://github.com/authy/authy-form-helpers#help-tooltip -->
  <!-- <%= link_to '?', '#', :id => 'authy-help' %> -->

  <%= authy_request_sms_link %>
  <%= authy_request_phone_call_link %>
  <%= submit_tag I18n.t('submit_token', {:scope => 'devise'}), :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting error in this line  verify_authy_form 
On inspecting the code of gem i found that i need `@authy_id` so i tried 
`<%@authy_id=User.find(session[:user_id]).authy_id%>`
in view no still no success.

This is my `Users::AuthyCustomController`, where i have overridden some of the methods as stated in gem

```
class Users::AuthyCustomController  < Devise::DeviseAuthyController

protected
def after_authy_enabled_path_for(resource)
  my_own_path
end

def after_authy_verified_path_for(resource)
  my_own_path
end

def after_authy_disabled_path_for(resource)
  my_own_path
end

def invalid_resource_path
  my_own_path
end

def authentication_sms    
end

def authentication_phone
  @authy_id=User.find(session[:user_id]).authy_id
  # redirect_to user_verify_authy_path
  # redirect_to user_verify_authy_path and return
end
end
```

I have googled, but I was not able to find a solution

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy#authy-api `verify_authy_form` is a helper so I wonder where I can read that code, I can not find the github page of this specific project

Comment: check it here https://github.com/authy/authy-devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/devise_authy_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting **error** `undefined method id for nil class`

This is the [form helper](https://github.com/authy/authy-devise/blob/master/lib/devise-authy/controllers/view_helpers.rb)

```
def verify_authy_form(opts = {}, &block)
  opts = default_opts.merge(:id => 'devise_authy').merge(opts)
  form_tag([resource_name, :verify_authy], opts) do
    buffer = hidden_field_tag(:"#{resource_name}_id", @resource.id)
    buffer << capture(&block)
  end
end
```

I belive that `@resource` is `nil` so when it does `@resource.id` triggers the **error**

I believe this form is managed from this [controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287240/customizing-the-views-in-authy-devise?noredirect=1#comment81526593_47287240)

```
# verify 2fa
def POST_verify_authy
  token = Authy::API.verify({
    :id => @resource.authy_id,
    :token => params[:token],
    :force => true
  })

  if token.ok?
    @resource.update_attribute(:last_sign_in_with_authy, DateTime.now)

    session["#{resource_name}_authy_token_checked"] = true

    remember_device if params[:remember_device].to_i == 1
    if session.delete("#{resource_name}_remember_me") == true && @resource.respond_to?(:remember_me=)
      @resource.remember_me = true
    end
    sign_in(resource_name, @resource)

    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(@resource)
  else
    handle_invalid_token :verify_authy, :invalid_token
  end
end
```

and you can prove that by checking and including the relevant output from `rake routes`. So maybe you should debug that two pieces of code, the controller action is responsible to feeding `@resource` to the `form`

Comment: @ Fabrizio thanks that solved the problem thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ Fabrizio have you used this gem devise-authy i am trying to redirect to specific page after user has successfully verified the otp but after the otp is submitted the #POST_verify_authy gets called where the user is sign_in and by default redirected to home page.Can you please give some suggestion how can i do this

Comment: @yogeshmanjhi https://github.com/authy/authy-devise#custom-redirect-paths-eg-using-modules you need to override those actions and include in that ovverriden action your `your_controller_path`. You can find `your_controller_path` with `rake routes` in the terminal. More about `path helpers` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers and controllers http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions